# Is there a regex search that'll match like this for as I need it done?

Tags: regex, minecraft

This is for my Minecraft modpack.

I am doing this in Visual Studio Code.

I am trying to write a regex expression that can be used to search and convert recipes on the vanilla crafting table to the Artisan Worktables mod's equivalent.

I've narrowed down the regex as much as I can.

I've got it down to having a separate regex search for shaped and shapeless recipes.

I am wanting to know if there is a singular regex search pattern that would work for both cases.

The replace field for everything is

```
RecipeBuilder.get("basic")
  .set$1($4)
  .setFluid(<liquid:water> * 250)
  .addTool(<artisanworktables:artisans_cutters_wood>, 1)
  .addOutput($3)
  .create();
```

Example shaped recipe

```
recipes.addShaped("minecraft:golden_rail", <minecraft:golden_rail> * 6, [[<ore:ingotGold>, null, <ore:ingotGold>], [<ore:ingotGold>, <ore:stickWood>, <ore:ingotGold>], [<ore:ingotGold>, <ore:dustRedstone>, <ore:ingotGold>]]);
```

Shaped recipe regex search

```
recipes.add(Shaped)\("(.+)", (.+), (\[\[(.+)\]\]\));
```

Example converted shaped recipe

```
RecipeBuilder.get("basic")
  .setShaped([[<ore:ingotGold>, null, <ore:ingotGold>], [<ore:ingotGold>, <ore:stickWood>, <ore:ingotGold>], [<ore:ingotGold>, <ore:dustRedstone>, <ore:ingotGold>]]))
  .setFluid(<liquid:water> * 250)
  .addTool(<artisanworktables:artisans_cutters_wood>, 1)
  .addOutput(<minecraft:golden_rail> * 6)
  .create();
```

Example shapeless recipe

```
recipes.addShapeless("minecraft:yellow_dye_from_dandelion", <minecraft:dye:11>, [<minecraft:yellow_flower>]);
```

Shapeless recipe regex search

```
recipes.add(Shapeless)\("(.+)", (.+), (\[(.+)\]\));
```

Example converted shapeless recipe

```
RecipeBuilder.get("basic")
  .setShapeless([<minecraft:yellow_flower>]))
  .setFluid(<liquid:water> * 250)
  .addTool(<artisanworktables:artisans_cutters_wood>, 1)
  .addOutput(<minecraft:dye:11>)
  .create();
```

Comment: Do not add visual-studio-code tag back please. It doesn't matter where you are coding your minecraft plugin and the question isn't specific to vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
recipes.add(Shaped|Shapeless)\("(.+)", (.+), (\[{1,2}(.+)\]{1,2}\));
```

Comment: I made a couple of changes and its fixed.
Marked your post as the answer.
https://bitbin.it/DYvgk19E/raw/